# Help with active area on screen less drawing tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet

I recently started digital art with a non screen drawing tablet, I set the active area to be more manageable on a wide screen monitor, but I lose track of the active area is there any way to get an on screen floating border that can be adjusted, even just a simple rectangle shape would be enough if there's any apps that can do that.

Comment: I don't know. But I have a tip: I have my Wacom set to *Mouse Mode* instead of *Pen Mode*. That is sooo much easier for me to manage. The pen simple moves the mouse cursor relatively to where it is instead of according to an absolute area on the tablet.

Comment: Probably the easiest thing would be to resize the application to that size and its frame will work as the border. Or is there a reason why you can't do that? — @Wolff, if you're using the stylus as a mouse that might make sense but not for any kind of drawing, right? I couldn't imagine drawing like that, but why have a drawing tablet only to use it as a mouse?

Comment: @Joonas, it still works as a pen like you would expect. Only difference is that the movement is *relative* instead of *absolute*. No matter where you place the pen on the tablet it simply takes control of the cursor wherever it is. It doesn't make the cursor jump to the corresponding position on the screen. Which, for me, is much more intuitive and relaxed.

Comment: @Wolff, wow... I never knew anyone would be drawing using the mouse mode... out of curiosity did you skip trying to get used to it in pen mode when you first started using it or did you decide you liked mouse mode better later? Cause I know for a lot of people the first few times/weeks with pen mode makes them wonder if they made a terrible mistake buying the thing.

Comment: @Joonas, I'm still practicing and draw a little for fun (it was a present). But I had another tablet earlier that I gave up on because I couldn't get used to the cursor jumping around every time I put it down in a new position. Discovering Mouse Mode was quite an eye opener for me. I just like it way more. I didn't know that someone would be considering it "doing it the wrong way".  No matter which mode, it takes many hours to get comfortable with a tablet.

Comment: @Wolff, I wouldn't say it's wrong... If it works... I think I just always saw it as some sort of remnant from when Intuos came with a wireless mouse that worked on top of the active area. I would recommend pushing through learning the pen mode... It's like learning to ride a bike. Minus the bike... :)

Comment: I map my *entire* tablet to my *entire* screen area. Then throw the mouse in a drawer where it's been collecting dust for *years*.  I only break out a mouse to install an OS and then the tablet drivers. Generally, with non-screen drawing tablets you need to use it *exclusively* for a week or so to acclimate yourself to it.

Comment: @Joonas, limited the border to the entire software I was using but I kept hitting different tools and moving stuff around so I tried making just the canvas area and I lose track of where I'm trying to draw, making it the entire screen on a wide screen monitor makes it unsuable. I just went back to using a mouse for now but will keep trying to improve on the tablet

Comment: Dustin, for what it's worth, I totally get the issue with any kind of wide monitor. It 100% makes sense to map a smaller area on the screen and then the issue is that you cant tell where the active area ends on your screen, which isnt the biggest issue, but you can easily over shoot it if you assume things go from corner to corner but they dont exactly. I have used this feature before though and I think using the application frame is your best bet. The only issue I foresee is if you want to use it with other apps too, it might not be possible unless you fit them all in that area.

Comment: But that is an issue whether or not you see the border of your active area. Not sure how people handle that in general. I was kinda surprised how little I found about drawing tablet usage on wide monitors. — I think hitting the wrong things accidentally might have more to do with not being used to it yet than not seeing the border. Like Scott said, it takes like a week or... I'd say a month depending on the use to get from it feeling a bit weird to it feeling just as natural as using a mouse or pen and paper.

Comment: One aspect is aiming before clicking. When you hover over the area like 1-2cm from the drawing tablet it already teleports the cursor but doesnt click. "Mastering" this is not instant either. But the point is you can slide your hand around while hovering above it to better aim your clicks so that you hit the things you want to click or continue a line exactly how you wanted to and that sort of stuff. You never have to actually blindly click things. Pretty sure it's just getting used to it that is the biggest hurdle here. If possible maybe it would help using it on a regular monitor at first?